# How to pass values to a Validator in order to save service call in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-validator

I have the following code from a ts file (component):

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getTripNames();
}

getInstruments() {
  this.tripService.getTripNames().subscribe(
    data => { this.tripNames = data; },
    err => console.error(err),
    () =>
      console.log(this.trips)
  );
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.tripForm = new FormGroup({
    newTripName: new FormControl('', {
      validators: Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        ValidateTrip.createValidator(this.tripNames)
      ]),
      updateOn: 'blur'
    })
  });

}
```

As you can see the trips are being fetched on load of the component (they are shown on the page and also on the console), the problem is that these values are not available when the `Validator` processed.
The `createValidator` is called but the values come as undefined.
I can inject service to the validator and fetch again the values from the restful service but it doesn't make any sense.
Any idea how make `this.tripNames` available inside the `Validator`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [asyncValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) when validation depending http request or another observable.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.tripForm = new FormGroup ({
    newTripName: new FormControl('', {
      validators:  Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]),
      asyncValidators: [tripNamesValidator.bind(this)],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    })
  });
}

tripNamesValidator() {
  return this.tripService.getTripNames()
    .map(tripNames=>{
      return youCondition?null:{errorName: 'error message'};
   }); 
}
```

Comment: In your solution, I have to go again to the service to fetch the values which is exactly what I try to avoid.

Comment: It's just simple example how to use `asyncValidators`. You can create `BehaviorSubject` and fetch data `onInit` then put data for validation in you `BehaviorSubject` and use it in `asyncValidator`

Comment: I'm not familiar with BehaviorSubject yet, can you update your answer to include how to use it.